# How do I bypass the purple screen to install my graphics drivers?

Tags: installation, grub2, graphics

Having identified a problem of lack of b43 graphics drivers which prevent me from getting beyond a purple screen I've been advised what commands to use to fix this. But I don't know how to access the commands to insert the install command. I can't open Terminal in Ubuntu because I can't get into it. I've been told to press escape when 'grub loading' message appears but I've never seen such a message. Whatever I press on start-up I just get the options to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. Then loads of text ending in the error message for lack of b43 firmware. Then the purple screen.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

**b43 is a network (wireless) driver, not a graphics driver**

That said, you want to add the `nomodeset` option when you boot to allow you to bypass the purple screen and install the drivers you need.

1. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting up, to get the Grub menu. Use the arrow keys to navigate/highlight the entry you want (usually the first one).

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit that entry, which will show you the details:

   [image]
3. Find the `linux` entry as shown above, use the arrow keys to get to it, and then  press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to get to that line's end (which may be on the next line!). Enter `nomodeset` as shown, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot to where you can successfully install your graphics drivers.

Comment: Thank you. But when I get to the Grub I get different options to those shown above. I get : normal mode, safe graphic mode, AcPI workarounds, verbose mode, Demo mode.If I press e on one of these I get a box with a continuous string of entries. I tried putting in nomodeset after rootflags=sync but got back to the purple screen with 'Ubuntu' in a slightly different typeface.